# How to center UILabel text top and bottom spaces

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, uistackview

I have a `UILabel` in a stackview in a content view that is in a tableview cell. Everything is working correctly and the cell is resizing but i cannot center the text in the `UILabel`. I always have strange spaces in the bottom of the text. Check out screen shot.

Yellow: content view
Green: stackview
Blue: label

**Additional info:** No static height for cells. The yellow view has top bottom and trailing and leading constraints plus horizontal and vertical aligned to super view same thing the stack view. The only thing that has constant height which I activate and deactivate through code is the button. So it hides and shows according to the cell. Stackview is fill proportionally.

The `UILabel` is `sizeToFit`

Also tried:

```
detailLbl.textAlignment = .center
detailLbl.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping //also tried byClipping
detailLbl.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```

The text inside i parse as **HTML**

```
"<p><font color=\"#cd1719\">V/. </font>…The Word of the Lord.<br><b></b><font color=\"#cd1719\">R/. </font><b>Thanks be to God.</b></p>"
```

Second screenshot

```
"<h6 lang=\"en\" style=\"color=#cd1719 !important; font-weight: normal !important\"><font color=\"#cd1719\" weight=\"normal\"><i>The alleluia is said or sung.</i></font></h6>"
```

This is an `NSAttributedString` extension I use for parsing HTML

```
 extension NSAttributedString {

    convenience init(htmlString html: String, font: UIFont? = nil, useDocumentFontSize: Bool = true) throws {
        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]

        let data = html.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        guard (data != nil), let fontFamily = font?.familyName, let attr = try? NSMutableAttributedString(data: data!, options: options, documentAttributes: nil) else {
            try self.init(data: data ?? Data(html.utf8), options: options, documentAttributes: nil)
            return
        }

        let fontSize: CGFloat? = useDocumentFontSize ? nil : font!.pointSize
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attr.length)
        attr.enumerateAttribute(.font, in: range, options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) { attrib, range, _ in
            if let htmlFont = attrib as? UIFont {
                let traits = htmlFont.fontDescriptor.symbolicTraits
                var descrip = htmlFont.fontDescriptor.withFamily(fontFamily)

                if (traits.rawValue & UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitBold.rawValue) != 0 {
                    descrip = descrip.withSymbolicTraits(.traitBold)!
                }

                if (traits.rawValue & UIFontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits.traitItalic.rawValue) != 0 {
                    descrip = descrip.withSymbolicTraits(.traitItalic)!
                }
                
                attr.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont(descriptor: descrip, size: fontSize ?? htmlFont.pointSize), range: range)
            }
        }

        self.init(attributedString: attr)
    }

}
```

And this is how I use it in the code

```
if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(htmlString: htmlTxt, font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: CGFloat(Constants.defualtContentDescriptionFontSize)), useDocumentFontSize: false) {
        cell.detailLbl.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: show constraints code ? do you set a static height for the table ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan no static height. The yellow view has top bottom and trailing and leading constraints plus horizontal and vertical aligned to super view same thing the stack view. The only thing that has constant height which I activate and deactivate through code is the button. So it hides and shows according to the cell. Stackview is fill proportionally

Comment: @KeghamK. - don't use Fill Proportionally... use `Fill`. Don't change the height constraint of your button. Set your button's `.isHidden` property to show / hide it. When hidden, the stack view will automatically remove the space it was taking up.

Comment: @DonMag tried that too no it didn't work. Yes no need to change constraints hidden is enough but still have this space in the bottom

Comment: @KeghamK. - show the code you are using to parse the html. Try starting with just a `UILabel` in your main view -- forget about embedding it in a stack view in a table view cell.

Comment: @DonMag I have updated the question with more code details

Comment: Try `stackView.alignment = .center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you are using **formatted** html text, which includes the "extra space."

For example, your first html text line includes `<p> </p>` tags.

This code creates two green-background labels, each the same width, each with no height constraint:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstLabel = UILabel()
        firstLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        firstLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        firstLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let secondLabel = UILabel()
        secondLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        secondLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        secondLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(firstLabel)
        view.addSubview(secondLabel)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // first label 40-pts from top, 20-pts on each side
            firstLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            firstLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            firstLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),

            // second label 40-pts from bottom of first label, 20-pts on each side
            secondLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            secondLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            secondLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            
        ])
        
        var htmlTxt = "<p><font color=\"#cd1719\">V/. </font>…The Word of the Lord.<br><b></b><font color=\"#cd1719\">R/. </font><b>Thanks be to God.</b></p>"
        
        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(htmlString: htmlTxt, font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: 24.0), useDocumentFontSize: false) {
            firstLabel.attributedText = attributedString
            //cell.detailLbl.attributedText = attributedString
        }

        htmlTxt = "<font color=\"#cd1719\">V/. </font>…The Word of the Lord.<br><b></b><font color=\"#cd1719\">R/. </font><b>Thanks be to God.</b>"
        
        if let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(htmlString: htmlTxt, font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Roman", size: 24.0), useDocumentFontSize: false) {
            secondLabel.attributedText = attributedString
            //cell.detailLbl.attributedText = attributedString
        }
    }

}
```

The output:

[image]

The difference between the two? For the second label, I removed the `<p> </p>` tags before processing the html with your extension.

Your second html text defines it as `h6` ... here's the output with that string:

[image]

Again, the difference between the two is that I removed the `h6` tag before processing the html.

You'll probably need to modify your extension to remove the paragraph tags, or set a paragraph style that would ignore them.

Comment: Thanks dear this is the correct answer. I also removed the stackview too. I will just replace the occurrences of the <p> and </p> tags with and empty string and I believe it will be adjusted